# NUMTODSINTERVAL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

Is there a function in SQL Server that is the same as `NUMTODSINTERVAL` in Oracle?

Comment: Might be helpful if you explained what NUMTODSINTERVAL does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In SQL Server time intervals for date arithmetic are always specified as integers. Take a look at the DATEADD and DATEDIFF functions for example. Since intervals are specified as integers you won't need a function to return a special interval type.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such function since there is no [INTERVAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151817.aspx) datatype in MSSQL.